# Trying to connect to AWS EC2 instance and getting session denied (publickey)?

Tags: openssh, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2

I use Windows 10 and can do this successfully in PowerShell:

```
ssh -i "bla.pem" ubuntu@blabla.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

However, when I try to do this in VSC Remote Explorer I get:

```
[17:25:05.139] Received install output: ssion denied (publickey).
[17:25:05.141] Failed to parse remote port from server output
```

This is my adapted config file:

```
Host aws-bla
  HostName blabla.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  IdentityFile C:\Users\xxx\.ssh\bla.pem
```

FWIW, I think adding `User ubuntu` to config file does the trick. But when I do this:

```
ssh -i "bla.pem" ubuntu@blabla.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Or try to connect from VSC it now hangs; even after restarting instance in AWS. What could the reason for this be?

Comment: So with the `User ubuntu` stuff you just added, do you still have a question?

Comment: no it seems to work-ish. mind you when I currently do: ssh -i "bla.pem" ubuntu@blabla.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com or try to connect from VSC it now hangs - even after restarting instance in AWS ... what could the reason for this be?

Comment: Good info. I added it to your question. Hope you get to figure this out.

Comment: Review the logs for the instance. SSH normally cannot restart an instance. Even if the OpenSSH server crashed the instance should not crash or restart. You probably have multiple problems.

Comment: thanks everyone. I was so proud of getting this to work and even managed to print hello world in python on the EC2 but now (as mentioned above) I am stuck with this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2990 frustrating!